# Fatal error starting debugging kernel every other deployment on Mac

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2

I'm writing a FireMonkey HD application on my Windows 32 bits machine, and deploying (remote debugging) it on my MacBook running Snow Leopard. I'm running the Delphi XE2 Trial.

Everything is working fine, except for one thing: **every other run** I hit the following error when I press F9:

> Fatal error starting debugging kernel: "Invalid debugger request".
>   Please save your work and restart Delphi XE2.

Restarting XE2 and running again cures this problem... for exactly one run, then I hit the same error again. Whether I stop the debugging run through CTRL-F2, or gracefully close the application on the Mac, makes no difference. It happens on every project (including new, empty ones with only a single FireMonkey form).The PAServer terminal has no information, it's still on "listen".

Anyone has any tips on how to avoid this issue?

Comment: I got it sometimes.. but only if I shutdown and restart the PAServer without restarting Delphi... To skip your issue, you can debug on win32 and run on osx instead of debugging (Ctrl F9), (if run works better than debug with your setup)...

Comment: Didn't restart PAServer, but good to hear there are other triggers for this behaviour. Are you suggesting I run on the Mac without a debugger attached? That'll probably work, but my ultimate goal is porting large protions of our 800k loc framework to the mac... those _ported_ bits are the ones falling over, and a debugger definitely makes the process of flipping them back up again rather more efficient than manual tracing/logging. :)

Comment: Debugger is helpful.. sure ;o)

Answer (score 1):

Installing the full version of Delphi XE2 (including update 1) seems to have fully solved my problem.

I've checked the [Bug Fix list](http://edn.embarcadero.com/article/41649) for any references, but no such luck. Oh well, problem is gone anyway.

**[EDIT]** And now, the very next day, the problem re-appears.

Answer (score 0):

Delphi 10 gives a similar adventure (Win32 --> Win32 target).  It's "business as usual" for the remote debugger.